# Hybris ProductModel Class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

```
/** <i>Generated constant</i> - Attribute key of <code>Product.priceQuantity</code> attribute defined at extension <code>catalog</code>. */

public static final String PRICEQUANTITY = "priceQuantity";

public class ProductModel extends ItemModel
{
    @Accessor(qualifier = "priceQuantity", type = Accessor.Type.SETTER) 
    public void setPriceQuantity(final Double value)    
    {
        getPersistenceContext().setPropertyValue(PRICEQUANTITY, value);
    }   

}
```

Hi All, I'm trying to understand the generated model class in SAP Hybris 6.2, this example is from from ProductModel class. Trying to understand this e.g. setter method, can anyone pls help in understanding the below questions?

- `getPersistenceContext()` //not sure where this method is coming from in this class, it appears to be repeated in every setter?
- `setPropertyValue()`; //is this a hibernate method, don't see any package imported in the class?
- `@Accessor(qualifier = "priceQuantity", type = Accessor.Type.SETTER)` //what this annotation means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- AbstractItemModel(ProductModel's super class) has getPersistenceContext() this method which returns its local variable ItemModelInternalContext

  - ItemModelInternalContext is interface which has method signature getPropertyValue() its implementation is in ItemModelContextImpl
  - Accessor explanation is here https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors

Comment: I am trying to search AbstractItemModel class in Hybris but have been unsuccessful.....the path mentioned in imports of ItemsModel class is not to be found in resources or anywhere, actually on searching a little more I found a jar file which is shown when searching the same AbstractItemModel class. Do you know if I can see the variables and methods of this Abstract file anywhere?

Comment: Not sure about others but, I use Intellij IDE - it decompiles and shows Hybris source code which are part of Jar files.